# Referring to objects in Java

Tags: java, object, reference

quick question regarding my program. My program deals with circle objects that bounce around on a JFrame window. When 2 circles collide the smaller circle is consumed by the larger one and smaller one disappears. The method that does this is called:

```
checkCollsion();
```

In my program I'm calling it as such:

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < blobs.length - 1; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = i + 1; j < blobs.length; j++ )
        {
            blobs[i].checkCollision( blobs[j] );
        }
    }
```

**My only question is, is that I do not understand how to reference blobs[i]. I get how to check if something collides, however I don't understand how I am suppose to compare blobs[i] with blobs[j] since in my method I can only pass in blobs[j] object.**

Here's code from my blob class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Blob extends BouncingBall {
    private int r;
    private int g;
    private int b;
    private Color c; 
    private BouncingBall bb;

    public Blob(int x, int y, int diameter, int windowSize) {
        super(x, y, diameter, windowSize);

    }

    public void setRandomColor(){
        Random r1 = new Random();
        Random r2 = new Random();
        Random r3 = new Random();
        r = r1.nextInt(256);
        g = r2.nextInt(256);
        b = r3.nextInt(256);
        c = new Color(r,g,b);
        setBackground(c);
    }

    public void setRandomDirection(){
        Random r1 = new Random();
        Random r2 = new Random();
        int rightOrLeft = r1.nextInt(2);
        int upOrDown = r2.nextInt(2);

        if (rightOrLeft == 0){
            xDelta = LEFT;
        }else{
            xDelta = RIGHT;
        }
        if (upOrDown == 0){
            yDelta = UP;
        }else{
            yDelta = DOWN;
        }

    }

    public void checkCollision(Blob blobs){


        //setRandomDirection();
        //setRandomColor();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `Blob` instances in `checkCollision`. The parameter `blobs` **and** `this`. For example,

```
public void checkCollision(Blob blobs) {
    // this is blobs[i] and blobs is blobs[j]
    if ((this.x + this.diameter) == (blobs.x + blobs.diameter)
            && ((this.y + this.diameter == blobs.y + blobs.diameter))) {
        // ...
    }
}
```